# Mobile Nav dropdown doesn't disappear after resizing window

Tags: javascript, html, css

The mobile nav icon disappears just fine to reveal the desktop nav when I expand the window, but the mobileNavSections div doesn't disappear when it's greater than the specfied screen width. The toggling function works as intended.

```js
function displayMobileNav(){
  var x = document.getElementById("mobileNavSections");
  if (x.style.display == "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.mobileNav {
  display: none;
}

#mobileNavSections {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width:100%;
  height: flex;
}

#mobileNavSections a {
  display:block;
  color: black;
  margin: 5%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity:0.5;
}

#mobileNavSections a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
} 


@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 768px){
    .mobileNav{
      display: block;
    }

    .mobileNav img {
      height: 30px;
    }

    .mobileNav:hover {
      cursor: grab;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="mobileNav" onclick="displayMobileNav()">
    <img src="images/menuicon.svg">
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="mobileNavSections">
  <a href="#About">About</a>
  <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">中文</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your JS only targets the `div` to hide, not the `nav`, so the `nav` stays visible.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes the javascript function works as intended, but it's the CSS part that doesn't work: I want the div to disappear when it's greater than that screen width

Comment: Your media query uses class selectors, but your initial CSS uses `id` selectors, which are more specific than class selectors and therefore don't get overridden by the media query. You should attempt to use class selectors for your base styling. Learn more about CSS specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and [here](https://specificity.keegan.st/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this css media query should finish hiding the nav part that you are not covering with the JS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px){
     #mobileNavSections{
          display:none;
     }
}
```

I would definitely recommend more of a mobile first when putting together the css. Media queries and overrides can quickly become a headache. Here are some tips and further reading:

Mobile first CSS is written like this:

Styles for mobile and styles that are common to all screen sizes

(no media query)

[icon name=icon-arrow-down]

Media query with a smallish min-width breakpoint

e.g. @media (min-width: 400px)

[icon name=icon-arrow-down]

Media query with a slightly larger min-width breakpoint

e.g. @media (min-width: 600px)

[icon name=icon-arrow-down]

Media query with a  larger still min-width breakpoint

e.g. @media (min-width: 960px)

One way to think of it is that you start with a mobile base and build up (or out, if you think in terms of widths).

https://www.mightyminnow.com/2013/11/what-is-mobile-first-css-and-why-does-it-rock/